# Handling Json response in table

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON Response as follows
JSON :

```
 var res =    {
      "response": {
        "status": {
          "code": "0",
          "message": "Success"
        },
        "service": {
          "servicetype": "3",
          "functiontype": "3000",
          "session_id": "966"
        },
        "data": {
          "profilesearchsnippet": [
            {
              "profileInfo": {
                "firstname": "Archita",
                "lastname": "v",
                "gender": "female",
                "country": "India",

              }
            },

            {
              "profileInfo": {
                "firstname": "Archita",
                "lastname": "V",
                "gender": "female",
                "country": "India",

              }
            },

            {
              "profileInfo": {
                "firstname": "Jayasree",
                "lastname": "Salavadi",
                "gender": "female",
                "country": "Afghanistan",

              }
            },

            {
              "profileInfo": {
                "firstname": "Kalai",
                "lastname": "Sundar",
                "gender": "female",
                "country": "India",

              }
            },

            {
              "profileInfo": {
                "firstname": "Singer",
                "lastname": "sing",
                "gender": "female",
                "country": "Afghanistan",

              }
            }

          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to fetch all firstname , country state city in a table.I tried assigning  profilesearchsnippet value to variable `var SearchData` and try fetching firstname by using profileinfo,since its object. I am missing  something somewhere need assistance.

HTML:

```
  <tr ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
        <td>{{searchData.profileInfo.firstname}}</td>
        <td> {{searchData.profileInfo.country}}</td>
      </tr>
```

JS:

```
var searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Your `JSON` is not valid.

[image]

**2.** Inside `ng-repeat` use `{{item.profileInfo.firstname}}` instead of `{{searchData.profileInfo.firstname}}`.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    var res = {
 "response": {
  "status": {
   "code": "0",
   "message": "Success"
  },
  "service": {
   "servicetype": "3",
   "functiontype": "3000",
   "session_id": "966"
  },
  "data": {
   "profilesearchsnippet": [{
     "profileInfo": {
      "firstname": "Archita",
      "lastname": "v",
      "gender": "female",
      "country": "India"
     }
    },

    {
     "profileInfo": {
      "firstname": "Archita",
      "lastname": "V",
      "gender": "female",
      "country": "India"
     }
    },

    {
     "profileInfo": {
      "firstname": "Jayasree",
      "lastname": "Salavadi",
      "gender": "female",
      "country": "Afghanistan"
     }
    },

    {
     "profileInfo": {
      "firstname": "Kalai",
      "lastname": "Sundar",
      "gender": "female",
      "country": "India"
     }
    },

    {
     "profileInfo": {
      "firstname": "Singer",
      "lastname": "sing",
      "gender": "female",
      "country": "Afghanistan"
     }
    }

   ]
  }
 }
};

$scope.searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
  <tr ng-repeat= "item in searchData">
        <td>{{item.profileInfo.firstname}}</td>
        <td> {{item.profileInfo.country}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON format is wrong. There are some extra `commas(,)` in your code. Below is the valid JSON.

```
var res = {
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "Success"
        },
        "service": {
            "servicetype": "3",
            "functiontype": "3000",
            "session_id": "966"
        },
        "data": {
            "profilesearchsnippet": [{
                    "profileInfo": {
                        "firstname": "Archita",
                        "lastname": "v",
                        "gender": "female",
                        "country": "India"

                    }
                },

                {
                    "profileInfo": {
                        "firstname": "Archita",
                        "lastname": "V",
                        "gender": "female",
                        "country": "India"

                    }
                },

                {
                    "profileInfo": {
                        "firstname": "Jayasree",
                        "lastname": "Salavadi",
                        "gender": "female",
                        "country": "Afghanistan"

                    }
                },

                {
                    "profileInfo": {
                        "firstname": "Kalai",
                        "lastname": "Sundar",
                        "gender": "female",
                        "country": "India"

                    }
                },

                {
                    "profileInfo": {
                        "firstname": "Singer",
                        "lastname": "sing",
                        "gender": "female",
                        "country": "Afghanistan"

                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to store `profilesearchsnippet` in `searchData`

Now in html do this.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in searchData">
    <td> {{item.profileInfo.firstname}} </td>
    <td> {{item.profileInfo.country}} </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be referencing `item` not `searchData` in your `td` tags.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in searchData">
    <td> {{item.profileInfo.firstname}} </td>
    <td> {{item.profileInfo.country}} </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your JS is wrong...

If you are using scope inside your controller... then bind the value to `scope`, not to on a fly var...
and if you use controller as, then bind your data to `this`

```
this.searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;

<.... ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
{{ctrl.searchData }}
</...>
```

otherwise

```
$scope.searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;

<.... ng-controller="myController">
{{searchData }}
</...>
```

Once you correct this... You also wrong where the Mike said... you need to bind your data to item... as you say there is an `item` inside `searchData`